# okhttp3.WebSocket: cancel() after onFailure()

Tags: websocket, okhttp

I've seen the following code several times:

```
public final class MyListener extends WebSocketListener {
  //...
  @Override 
  public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
    webSocket.cancel();
  }
}
```

Seems like developers want to enforce resource cleanup after a failure happens. But is that really necessary/useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary. OkHttp will release all held resources in response to a failure.